# Нестандартное (для меня) поведение параметров в контролере asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Когда-то в Web Api 2 я мог написать такой action:

```
public class INP
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}
public string Post(INP con)
{
    return con.value;
}
```

и все отлично работало как с `ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` отправленным от клиента, так и с `ContentType: application/json`.

Однако, в asp.net core все не так просто: с вышеприведенным кодом `ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` работает, а вот `ContentType: application/json` оставляет мне просто null в коде. Если обрамлять параметр атрибутом `[FromBody]`, то ситуация меняется: с `ContentType: application/json` все отлично, а вот с `ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` мне вовсе приходит ответ вида `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

Итак, сам вопрос: как в asp.net core написать action, который бы принимал мне параметр разных `ContentType`'ов, как это было в Web Api 2? И почему поведение изменилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот вопрос можно решить таким путем: нужно создать две разные Action method-ы, которые смогут специфически байндить данные необходимые для отправки, а затем делегировать обработку вызовов к общему методу.

### Например:

```
public class MyController : Controller  
{
    //для ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(MyClass myclass){
        return DoSomething(myclass);   
    } 

    //и для ContentType: application/json
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult IndexFromBody([FromBody] MyClass myclass){
        return DoSomething(myclass);   
    } 

    private IActionResult DoSomething(MyClass myclass){
        // сделай тут что нибудь с myclass
        // ...
        // ...
        return Json(myclass);
    }
}
```

### Зачем Изменения?

Разве раньше не было попроще? Может быть, но по мнению Дэмиана Эдвардса в сообществе Standup, основная причина это безопасность, в частности -  предотвращение [Межсайтовой подделки запросов (CSRF)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0).

### UPDATE

Вы должны решить эту проблему routing-ом, но если вы попытаетесь отобразить две вышеуказанные действия по одному и тому же маршруту, это приведет к ошибке. Решением этого будет создание пользовательского маршрута и вызов соответствующего метода по заголовку. Я понимаю что это требует больше усилий, чем этого стоит, но они говорят что эти изменения в целях безопасности, я не стал глубоко изучать как именно это предотвращает CSRF. Вы можете погуглить или же посмотреть [тут](http://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: это не совсем то решение, так как при вызове такого rest api система маршрутизации не сможет выбрать один из двух Post-методов.
А как это поможет предотвратить CSRF?

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Comment: "Решением этого будет создание пользовательского маршрута и вызов соответствующего метода по заголовку" - из этого предложения я мало что понял, можно подробнее?

Comment: 1. При чём тут CSRF, это же post-запрос. 2. x-www-form-urlencoded ведь в body, а не в адресе. 3. Чем json безопаснее?

Comment: От кривых рук и непонимания темы разработки ничего не спасёт, но всё чаще виднеются такие якобы фиксы безопасности повсеместно - во всех фреймворках всех языков. Маэстро программирования, устанавливающие правила, тем самым пытаются повысить качество кода, повышая его сложность? В чём причина сей тенденции?